# Object being passed using webmethod, loses some values, but not all

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, web-services, asmx

I'll try to explain everything clearly.

when calling a webmethod

```
[WebMethod]
public Profile synchronize(string MID, DeviceUploadData data)
```

The object DeviceUploadData has many properties, and a few of them are array's.  My question is about the array specifically.  It loses it's value once it's received on the webmethod end.

This is the property inside DeviceUploadData

```
Private data() As DataObject
Public Property Data() As DataObject()
    Get
        Return Me.data
    End Get
    Set(value As DataObject())
        Me.data = value
    End Set
End Property
```

This is the DataObject object inside

```
 <System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.225"), _
         System.SerializableAttribute(), _
         System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute(), _
         System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code"), _
         System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute([Namespace]:="http://somethingsomething")> _
        Public Class DataObject
            Dim _calories As Double
            Public Property Calories() As Double
                Get
                    Return _calories
                End Get
                Set(value As Double)
                    _calories = value
                End Set
            End Property
End Class
```

This is the DeviceUploadData object on the webmethod end

```
public class DataObject
    {
        private List<DataObject> _data;
        public List<DataObject> data
        {
            get { return _data; }
            set { _data = value; }
        }
}
```

This is the DataObject on the webmethod end

```
public class DataObject
    {
        #region class variables
        double _calories;
        public double Calories
        {
            get { return _calories; }
            set { _calories = value; }
        }
}
```

So the DataObject is populated with data, then once passed, on the other end, some of the DataObject properties are no longer populated.  I haven't included the other properties in this example.

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it!  All parameters and methods have to named exactly the same in the client and web object.

I guess it would be hard to see in my example since I've labled them the same.

Hope this helps some people out there.